# how to use "select concat(col)" in siddhi aggregation query?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

How to get all data of one column in the aggregation siddhi query. For example, i have the data as:

```
column1 column2 column_uuid
1       a       uuid1
2       a       uuid1
3       a       uuid3
4       b       uuid4
```

I want to use the siddhi query as:

```
define stream Input (column1 int, column2 string, column_uuid string);

define stream Output (column2 string, amount long, uuid string);

@info(name='query')
from Input#window.time(30 sec)
select column2, count() as amount, concat(column_uuid) as uuid
group by column2
having amount > 2
insert into Output;
```

and i want get result as:

```
Event{timestamp=xxx, data=[a, 3, "uuid1,uuid2,uuid3"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Siddhi, there are two types of functions. Regular ["function"](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#aggregate-function)s, and ["aggregate-function"](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#aggregate-function)s. Since [str:concat()](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-execution-string/api/4.0.12/#concat-function) is not an aggregate-function, you can't use that to get your desired outcome.

Therefore, you may have to write your own `custom:concat()` aggregate function to get that expected result. Please refer to following samples on writing a custom aggregate functions ([samples](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/tree/master/modules/siddhi-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/query/selector/attribute/aggregator)). To get the above output, you can simply keep a global string variable within your custom attribute aggregator and append to that in `processAdd(Object data)` method (similar to [this](https://github.com/grainier/custom-siddhi-extensions/blob/master/siddhi-extension-table-row-attribute-aggregator/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/extension/custom/TableRowAttributeAggregator.java#L52)).